# How can I have a for loop where each number adds itself to the next in the iteration?

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop going 1-20. How can I have each number add itself to the next each time it loops?

The title says it all I have no clue I'm very new to JavaScript and I'mm more of a while loop guy.

```
let mainDiv14 = document.getElementById("main");
let myParagraph14 = document.createElement("p");
let myTextNode14 = document.createTextNode("KATA 14");
myParagraph14.append(myTextNode14);
mainDiv14.append(myParagraph14);
let max13 = 20;
let oneToTwentyFive14 = [];

function array6() {
  for (i = 1; i <= max13; i++) mainDiv14.append(i + " ");
}

array6();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand well your request you want to sum the actual value of 'i' with all the previous 'i' for each iteration the value ? And at the end you want to see the result '210' in this case for example ?

You have to define a variable outside the loop and increment it in the loop

So it must be something like :

```
function array6() {
  //Define the variable
  let sum = 0;
  for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++){
          //increase it at each iteration
          sum += i
  }
  // put the value where you want
  mainDiv14.append(sum);
}
```

Comment: thiat is exactly what i want but that didnt work :(

Comment: Ohh i've seen i've put append(i), instead of append(sum) 

But i just tried it and i have 210 which appears. 

function array6() {

    let sum = 0;

      for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++){

        sum += i

      }

    document.getElementById('test').append(sum)
}

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like so?

```
 for (i = 1; i <= max13; i++) mainDiv14.append(i + i + 1 + " ");
```

Result:

```
KATA 14

3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39 41
```

Comment: Try this

`function array6() {
  let result = 0
  let calculationString = ""
  for (i = 1; i <= max13; i++){
    calculationString += i + " + "  
    result += i
  } 
   mainDiv14.append(calculationString + " = " + result);
}`